# Category and subcategory does not match

Tags: php, join, categories

I have issues with category and subcategory fields.

shortly, I made category like this: **literature**, and want to make drop down sub menu like this: **poetry, novel, non-fiction.**

I receive all the categories on the website, but can't get subcategory field at all.

Here is my code:

```
     $category=htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['category']);
if(isset($category)){
    $avt=mysql_query("select * from  category order by id asc");
    while($category_id=mysql_fetch_array($avt))
    {
        ?> 

        <li><a href="#"> <k style="font-size:11px;"> <? 
   echo $category_id['catname'];            
    } }
    ?>  </k> </a> 




     <?



     $subcategory=htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['subcategory']);
if(isset($subcategory)){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM category as t1, subcategory as t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.'$_REQUEST[subcat_id]'");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))

    { ?>


    <ul style="z-index:101;">
   <li> <k>  <a href="index.php?do=cat&id=<? echo $data['id'];?>" style="border-bottom:1px solid #CECECE; position:relative; left:-40px; font-size:11px; ">&nbsp; <?php echo $data["subcat_name"]; ?> </a> </k></li> 

   <?  } }

    ?>
```

And here is the mysql:

**category**

```
id
catname
```

**Subcategory**

```
id
subcat_id
subcat_name
```

That's all. I would be grateful if some can help me to solve this. (I am beginner obviously)

Thank you

Comment: Are you encountering any error messages when trying to reach subcategory? Including those here would be helpful.

Comment: no, there are no errors shown.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are a beginner, I would suggest you probably heavily retool this. Start with your database connection. `mysql_` functions are deprecated (not recommended for use) in the latest v5 of PHP and removed altogether in PHP v7 because they are security risk and are poorly implemented by most. Use PDO or MySQLi instead. I prefer [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), so I will demonstrate that:

```
# Create the connection thusly, fill in your own credentials
$con = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase", $username, $password);
```

Next, you should know the difference between `isset` and `empty`. In your case, your `isset` will throw a warning if `$_REQUEST['category']` is not set. When you create your own variable, it's guaranteed to be set when you check it because you manually just created it.

This will throw a warning if `$_REQUEST['category']` is not set because you assign it before you check it:

```
$category = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['category']);
```

This WILL NOT throw a warning because you are checking if `$_REQUEST['category']` is set yet. If not, assign `$category` to `false` by default:

```
# I like to use a ternary when there are only two options, but you can use if/else
$category = (isset($_REQUEST['category']))? htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['category'])) : false;

# This part now checks if the value that you created is NOT EMPTY because you
# have just created it, so checking if it is set is illogical
if(!empty($category)):
    # Now we use our connection here to query.
    # Here we can use query() because we don't have any variables to add into the query,
    # so it's safe to use this short version
    $avt = $con->query("select * from  category order by id asc");
    # Same while loop, just use the PDO version of fetching the results
    while($category_id = $avt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>

        <?php
        /**
         * I'm not sure why you are using a "k" tag, so just combine with "a" tag
         * also, though you can use <? as a php open, it's not recommended
         * lastly, you have the close tag for "a" outside the loop, that is bad syntax
         * since the open is inside the loop
         */
        ?>

        <li><a href="#" style="font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $category_id['catname'] ?></a></li>

    <?php endwhile ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Now that the top part is finished, you have the same issues (plus a couple more) on this second part of the code:

```
# It's also worth noting here you have set this variable, but you don't actually use it...?
# Secondly, you are checking for "subcategory" here, but in the code below you are injecting "subcat_id"...should they match??
$subcategory = (isset($_REQUEST['subcategory']))? htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['subcategory'])) : false;

if(!empty($subcategory)):
    # Here is where you need to make a detour with your script. What you are doing is unsafe.
    # You can not inject that value right into the sql. You need to "prepare", "bind value", and "execute" it
    $subcat_id = $_REQUEST['subcat_id'];
    # First prepare using ? as placeholders for the value you want to search for
    # The naming convention on the "subcat_id" column I assume is actually the
    # the parent category? If so, maybe it should be called "parent_id" or "category_id"??
    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM category as t1, subcategory as t2 WHERE t1.id = ? AND t2.subcat_id = ?");
    # Now you want to execute for those two question marks (?)
    # There are a few ways to prepare and bind parameters, this way is easy
    # and you can visually see what we are trying to accomplish
    $sql->execute([$subcat_id, $subcat_id]) ?>

    <!-- you probably don't want to be looping this (or it's close tag) -->
    <ul style="z-index:101;">

    <?php
    # Same type of thing as your first block of code
    while($data = $sql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>

        <li><a href="index.php?do=cat&id=<?php echo $data['id'] ?>" style="border-bottom:1px solid #CECECE; position:relative; left:-40px; font-size:11px; ">&nbsp;<?php echo $data["subcat_name"] ?> </a></li> 

    <?php endwhile ?>

    <!-- end list -->
    </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

The final conclusion here is that you have some work to be done before you get to the main problem which is likely your SQL statement and the value you are querying. I would suggest reading up on any of the concepts mentioned that you are not familiar with.

Comment: Dear Rasclatt, thank you very much for your kind advise. Now I will try to follow it step by step

Comment: No problem. You want to make sure the connection works first before you do anything else (it should throw an exception if not). Then simulate a request and make sure the next part works, and don't move on until you have the previous part(s) is fully working. I would not just copy and paste it all then go back try to troubleshoot it all at once.

Comment: If you are using PDO then you should disable emulated prepares and provide correct charset in DSN, otherwise your code could still be vulnerable to SQL injection. Please read this article to find out how to connect properly with PDO: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn

Comment: `(isset($_REQUEST['category']))? htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['category'])) : f` can be simply written as `htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['category'] ?? ''))`

Comment: `while($data = $sql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` is probably redundant since `$sql` is already traversable. Just do `foreach($sql as $data)`

Comment: `if(!empty($category))` is just `if($category)`

Comment: All your comments are valid and I am aware the connection should have emulation off however for purposes of demonstration and not to overwhelm the OP who has noted they are a beginner, the simplest connection is demonstrated—which is much more secure that `mysq_`. The OP is free to explore settings for PDO. Who knows what version of PHP the OP has so  `??` will not work if they are using below 5.6, and yes, `query()` can be traversed. The OP is free refactor at will.

Comment: I should also point out that the OP should reference the true authority on PDO for php will be the manual/documentation itself. All the info contained (and more) on your linked site is already written in the manual.